# Why does readBigInt64BE return a number that is not equal to it's original hex value?

Tags: node.js, hex, buffer, bigint

I have the following buffer:

```
<Buffer bf 58 e6 c6 00 8f fd 32 84 0f d1 d4 bd 7f ba 95 fa f1 b0 af cf 2a 54 43 49 f5 0f 42 e6 c3 60 e2 a5 1b 05 61 30 3a 75 50 42 60 ff ff 2e 57 d7 1f 8a da ... 269 more bytes>
```

Why is it that the following are not equal?

```
0xbf58e6c6008ffd32 //13788023997282124000
Number(buffer.readBigInt64BE(0)) // -4658720076427429000
```

Unsurprisingly, the little endian version returns another number also:

```
Number(buffer.readBigInt64LE(0)) // 3674250104503949300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0xbf58e6c6008ffd32` is considered to be a unsigned int (why, I don't know, I will need to also figure that out), so I need to read a big unsigned 64bit integer (`readBigUInt64BE` instead of `readBigInt64BE`).